# Showing inequality for points in$[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $x,y,z,w\in[0,1]$ with $x\leq z$ and $y\leq w$. Show that $x+y-xy\leq z+w-zw$.

Now $xy\leq zw$ and $x+y\leq z+w$ but from here how to show that $x+y-xy\leq z+w-zw$ ?

Comment: FYI, as indicated in [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419190/602049), one way to solve your question involves using [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1-x)(1-y) \geq (1-z)(1-w) $ because $(1-x) \geq (1-z) (\geq 0)$ and $(1-y) \geq (1-w) (\geq 0)$. Expanding we get  $1-x-y+xy \geq 1-z-w+zw$. Cancel $1$ and multiply by $(-1)$.